# Function changes the global list in python instead of local list

Tags: python, list, global-variables

I have this code written in Python:

```
def trick(l,i):
    if i==1:
        return l[0];
    else :
        return l[1]
def foo(x):
    x[0] = 'def'
    x[1] = 'abc'
    return x[1]
q = ['abc', 'def']
print(trick(q,1) == foo(q))
print(trick(q,1) == foo(q))
print(trick(q,0) == foo(q))
```

The output is this:

```
True
False
True
```

Why does the second print statement print "False" even though the second and the first print statements are the same. And when I visualized this code in Python tutor I got to know that the foo(x) function actually changes/swaps the elements in the original/global list 'q' even though 'x' should have local scope.

I can't understand this. Please help.

Comment: `x` is mutable. Nothing to do with the scope. you changed the items in `x`

Comment: You don't have separate global and local lists. There's only one list here. See https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Yep, I changed the items in x, not in q. so in the second print statement, I am calling the same statement but the output is False. Why so? I thought q remained the same and only x changed.

Comment: @user2357112 Thank you so much. You can reply as an answer so I can mark it as the correct one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you do have separate global and local variables, you don't have separate global and local lists. Both `q` and `x` refer to the same list; the parameter passing mechanism doesn't make an implicit copy of the list. (Python almost never makes implicit copies.)